# ObjectListView change color on column click

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, objectlistview

My objectlistview is changing the color if i click on the 5th column. But I don´t know why because i didnt created an event or something...
this is how it normally looks like: [image]

And this is how it looks like when i click on the column "queue":
[image]

Is this just a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You mean the foreground color? What happens if you click on the other columns? Does the column have to be clickable?

Comment: Yes the foregroundcolor. If I click on a other column it happens the same. And yes I need the column to be sortable.

Comment: Could be a bug. You use `UseHyperlinks = true` I guess? What happens if you set it to false?

Comment: It stays the same. It always change the color to blue...

Comment: Hmm I never experienced this. I suspected the column "Ticketnummer" to have something to do with it because it contains a link and thus is colored blue. Maybe that somehow influences the rest of the row. The "first" column of a OLV gets some special treatment IIRC. What happens if you remove that whole column from the OLV?